# Why am I getting two different screen dimensions in different projects (Swift)?

Tags: swift, uiview, sprite-kit

I just finished a very rough draft of my first app whilst learning Swift. So I decided to remake the app so that my code would be cleaner/more compliant, etc.

I don't use storyboards,
I launch from GameViewControler,
both apps are set for a minimum iOS of 13.5,
and both are run on the iPhoneX simulator...as well as my iPhoneX itself.

But for some reason in each different app, I am getting different screen sizes! Am going to assume I did something different when I "created" the new project, but am unable to distinguish what that is.

Here is my entire GameViewController.swift file and have included a photo of the different screen sizes. I break right after I get both the bounds and native bounds.

[Two different screen sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28ZZc.gif)

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

            var wPix = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width
            var hPix = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height
            var wPoi  = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            var hPoi  = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

            var scene : GameScene!
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                     scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: wPoi, height: hPoi))


            scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            scene.backgroundColor = .red
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
            view.isHidden = false
            view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
            view.showsPhysics = true
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that unlike my old project, there was no Launch Screen.storyboard in my new project. Since I just started learning this language I don't recall whether I added it manually before, or Xcode 11 included it automatically. Am now on Xcode 12.x

The gist of the problem, as I understand it, was that without the launch screen storyboard the screen size is set set to the smaller dimensions.

Someone gave me the link below which explained what and why it was happening.

[Main screen size is always 320x480?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327459/main-screen-size-is-always-320x480/48327639#48327639)

After reading the answer supplied by the link above, I also came upon the webpage below which helped me as well.

[Using a Launch Screen Storyboard](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard/)